# XNA- Rotating around another model

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

Lets say I have a model with multiple meshes. **Mesh A** is at position `PositionA = new Vector3(5,0,10)`. And **mesh B** is at position `PositionB = new Vector3(7,0,9)`. How can I rotate **mesh B** around **meshes A** pivot point, or its centre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xna, you can orbit `positionB` around `positionA` like this:

```
Matrix orbit = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(someAxis, someAngle);
positionB = Vector3.Transform(positionB - positionA, orbit) + positionA;
MeshBworld.translation = positionB;
```

where `someAxis` is a unit length vector representing the direction of the pivot axis and `someAngle`represents the amount of single frame orbiting rotation in radians. `MeshBworld` is simply Mesh B's world transform... whatever you've named it.